# Cache BigQuery queries

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I am building an App Engine Flexible front end that uses BigQuery data. However, the queries run for about 30 seconds. Is there a way to cache these somewhere so that the data is returned faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your option is using [`configuration.query.useQueryCache`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query.useQueryCache)

This property tells whether to look for the result in the query cache. The query cache is a best-effort cache that will be flushed whenever tables in the query are modified. Query cache is only available when a query does not have a destination table specified

See more in [`Using Cached Query Results`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results)